# Is it possible to set a role privileges by postgres user?

Tags: postgresql

We are using a remote connection by postgres user to set the PostgreSQL DB in RDS on AWS.

There is an `iam_ops` user with `ops` role in the DB. If use it in the same AWS account to set default table privileges to the another rule `readwrite`, it's possible.

After it, if `ops` role create new tables in the future, `iam_app_user` with `readwrite` role can use it.

But we want to run all these settings by postgres user from a remote server. Since the `iam_ops` role is using by IAM authentication from RDS, it seems postgres user can't do the grant task as same as the `iam_ops` can do.

```
CREATE USER iam_ops WITH LOGIN;
CREATE USER iam_app_user WITH LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE ops;
CREATE ROLE readwrite;
GRANT rds_iam TO iam_ops;
GRANT ops TO iam_ops;
GRANT readwrite TO iam_app_user;
GRANT rds_iam TO iam_app_user;

-- create and use a db

CREATE SCHEMA main;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA main TO ops;
GRANT CREATE, USAGE ON SCHEMA main TO ops;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA main TO readwrite;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA main TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA main GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, TRUNCATE ON TABLES TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA main FOR ROLE ops GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, TRUNCATE ON TABLES TO readwrite;
```

I think the postgres user can do everything. Is it really truth that it has some limitation as this case?

Current roles

```
postgres=> \du
                                                                          Role List
       Role           |                                   Attribute                              |                        Group
----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 iam_app_user         |                                                                          | {rds_iam,readwrite}
 iam_ops              |                                                                          | {rds_iam,ops}
 ops                  | Can't login                                                              | {}
 postgres             | Can create role, database                                               +| {rds_superuser}
 rds_iam              | Can't login                                                              | {}
 rds_superuser        | Can't login                                                              | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend,rds_replication,rds_password}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that `postgres`, if you can use that user, is no superuser in a hosted database.

Comment: I listed some roles. The `postgres` belongs to `rds_superuser` group.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So this way can make it be a superuser? `ALTER USER postgres WITH SUPERUSER;`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Then where? The configuration file?

Comment: If you want to use a hosted database like Amazon RDS, you cannot get a superuser. To get a superuser, run PostgreSQL on your own machine.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Okay, thank you very much.  [rds_superuser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Roles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name 'postgres' has no inherent special powers.  It is common (and often the default for own-hosted environments) to name your most powered user that name, but is not mandatory.  If you chose some other name, then that other name is what you have to use.